# Initialise member variables from parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I can't figure out how to make a generic initialiser function, which creates a new object for a specific member variable.

Let's say I have a `Foo` object, which has two `Bar` members.

```
class Bar {

public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();
};


class Foo {

public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

private:

    void init(Bar * x);

    Bar * a;
    Bar * b;

};
```

Now I want to initialise both `Bar` members in the same way:

```
Foo::Foo(){

    init(a);
    init(b);

}

void Foo::init(Bar * x) {

    x = new Bar();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

The init function in `Foo` should create a new `Bar()` for member `a` and member `b`. However the addresses for the member `a` and the local parameter `x` are different (i.e. Foo.a is not initialised). How can I initialise `a` and `b` inside the `init` function?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `init` needs to take its parameter by reference:

```
void Foo::init(Bar*& x) {
    x = new Bar();
}
```

That way, the `new Bar` that you are allocating actually gets to `a` and `b`. Otherwise, you're just allocating a temporary (and leaking it) twice.

Alternatively, you could have `init()` be named `create()` (or equivalent) and just return a `new Bar`:

```
Bar* Foo::create() {
    return new Bar;
}
```

So that your constructor can be:

```
Foo() {
    a = create();
    b = create();
}
```

Or simply:

```
Foo()
    : a(create())
    , b(create())
{ }
```